# Strategy for JSP Filters chained through grouped wild characters

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, filter

Say for example I have a filter that responds to a mapping named "/admin".

It forwards to other mappings called through "/admin/foo" towards "/admin/bar" etc.

Is this a concrete strategy for building up a JSP page through the final mapping? Or is there a better way?

And btw, is it possible to reject a call to /admin/[some_other_mapping] if it did not come from the previous filter/servlet?

For example. Here is a chain of filters. Since filters, assumingly from what I have learned, do not know what the servlets are doing or are independent from them, I will not include them in the chain.

/admin -> /admin/foo -> /admin/bar -> /admin/finish -> render JSP

Case one : If I am in /admin/foo, and did not come from /admin, I will return to /admin.
Case two : If I am in /admin/bar, and did not come from /admin/foo, I will return to /admin.

This is in order to complete the chain without any erratic effect on the rendered JSP.

Comment: Are you using any frameworks, paste the actual code and tells the problem, then only I can discover a solution for you...

Comment: No. It is by client specification that no framework must be used. I will place the code as soon as I can.